# GMSMapView animateWithCameraUpdate causing UI issue

Tags: ios, gmsmapview

[self->gmsMapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:self->mapBounds withPadding:50]];

mapBounds have many points.

animateWithCameraUpdate causing some space on top of mapview and on tapping any where on map it adjust mapview to proper bounds.

NOTE:
using  'GoogleMaps', '~> 6.2'
using iOS version 16.0.2 and 16.1

Please let me know if any workaround, I tried animating map again but that doesn't worked.

[image: Map Drawn leaving some space]